# whether cookie will maintain same jsessionid when we send different requests from portlet server to remote web application server?

Tags: java

whether cookie will maintain same jsessionid when we send different requests from portlet server to remote web application server?

Answer (score 1):

I think you're referring to WSRP

From the docs

http://www.oasis-open.org/committees/download.php/10953/wsrp-faq-draft-0.30.html

Does WSRP have a concept of sessions?

> Yes. In a GetMarkup call, the Producer
>   may optionally return a
>   SessionContext, which contains a
>   sessionID to identify the session.
>   This should not be confused with a
>   session which could be established
>   between a user-agent (browser) and a
>   Consumer.The Consumer should supply
>   this sessionID on future invocations
>   of getMarkup and
>   performBlockingInteraction in order to
>   not lose state the Producer is storing
>   for the user's interactions. If a
>   Consumer does not invoke this portlet
>   before this interval, the Producer may
>   terminate the session associated with
>   the sessionID. For more information,
>   search for sessionID in the WSRP
>   Specification.